# simulation of sensors using cooja simulator

Tags: android-sensors, contiki, cooja

I am trying to simulate sensor node with limited computing resources and limited memory using cooja simulator. I would like to know that how can I vary the memory size and find its effect on speed.

Answer (score 0):

you can run COOJA by `ant run_bigmem` command. this command will assign the maximum of available memory to COOJA simulator.